# pandasでファイル中のTSVフォーマット部分のデータのみを読み取りたい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

処理情報+TSVフォーマットの結果データという特殊フォーマットのファイルから
TSVフォーマットの結果データのみを、pandasのデータフレームに保持するにはどうすればよいでしょうか?

動作環境
OS: Windows10
Python: Ver3.7.5
Pandas: Ver0.25.3

特殊フォーマットファイルのサンプルは以下の通りの内容です

```
#TimeStamp 20200303 104030
#Fileinfo Name Size ProcID
Data1 111 222 333 abc ...
Data2 444 555 666 xyz ...
...
```

このように#から始まる処理情報(1,2行目)の下に結果データ(3行目以降)が続きます
処理情報の列数と結果データの列数は一致しません

よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 実行するOSは何でしょうか？利用可能ツールはpython限定ですか？(Pythonと他のツールの併用は可ですか？)

Comment: ご指摘を受けて動作環境を追記しました
利用可能ツールはpython限定になります

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.read_csv`でパラメータに`comment='#'`を追加して試してみてください。

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv)

> **comment** : str, optional
>   Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. This parameter must be a single character. Like empty lines (as long as skip_blank_lines=True), fully commented lines are ignored by the parameter header but not by skiprows. For example, if comment='#', parsing #empty\na,b,c\n1,2,3 with header=0 will result in ‘a,b,c’ being treated as the header.
>
> 行の残りを解析しないことを示します。行の先頭で見つかった場合、その行は完全に無視されます。このパラメーターは単一の文字でなければなりません。空行と同様に（限りskip_blank_lines=True）、完全にコメント化された行はパラメーターヘッダーによって無視されますが、skiprowsによっては無視されません 。たとえばcomment='#'、で解析 #empty\na,b,c\n1,2,3するheader=0と、「a、b、c」がヘッダーとして処理されます。